# Unable to stop moveable timeline

Tags: jquery, timeline, timeline.js, chap-links-library

I am using vis.js for timeline its working fine for me. but I am unable to stop moveable the timescale .i already try that movable configuration option that is not working for me can anyone suggest me how I can stop movable the timeline and I just want to fix my timeline scale. for example like only 120 minutes.

```
var options = {
autoResize:false,
moveable:false,
 orientation: 'top',
  };
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the same Min and Max zoom values, each set at 120 minutes.

```
var options = {
   "zoomMin": 1000 * 60 * 120, // this is one hour in milliseconds
   "zoomMax": 1000 * 60 * 120  //same thing
};
```